Custom JsonConverter for serializing JSON to abstract class
I am working on deserializing a complicated json structure as following, which "id" under "events" represent
"events": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "actions": [
    {
        "id": 8,
        "values": {
            "obj_id":160,
            "url": "https://www.myurl.com/"
        }
    },
    {
        "id":15,
        "values":{
            "obj_id":182,
            "scale":200
        }
    }
    ]
}
]
    

I have an abstract ActionBase class and multiple derived classes, different values base on different action id.
public class Events
{
    public int id;
    public ActionsHolder[] actions;
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(BaseConverter))]
public class ActionsHolder
{
    public int id { get; set; } = -1;
    public ActionBase values { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ActionBase : ActionsHolder
{
    public int obj_id { get; set; }
}

public class OpenURLAction : ActionBase
{
    //Action id 8 = Open URL
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class ScaleAction : ActionBase
{
    //Action id 15 = Scale
    public float scale { get; set; } = 1;
}

public class BaseSpecifiedConcreteClassConverter : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter(Type objectType)
    {
        if (typeof(ActionsHolder).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) && !objectType.IsAbstract)
        {
            return null; 
        }
            
        return base.ResolveContractConverter(objectType);
    }
}

public class BaseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    static JsonSerializerSettings SpecifiedSubclassConversion = new JsonSerializerSettings() 
    { 
        ContractResolver = new BaseSpecifiedConcreteClassConverter() ,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(ActionsHolder));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject joAction = JObject.Load(reader);

        JObject joValues = (JObject)joAction["values"];
        switch (joAction["id"].Value<int>())
        {
            case 8:
                return new ActionsHolder
                {
                    id = joAction["id"].Value<int>(),
                    values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenURLAction>(joValues.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion)
                };
            case 15:
                return new ActionsHolder
                {
                    id = joAction["id"].Value<int>(),
                    values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ScaleAction>(joValues.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion)
                };
            default:
                return null;
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();returns false
    }
}

However, it doesn't work.
How can my custom converter deserialize only actions properties and default converter for others...
Anyone can help?

Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] as indicated by [ask].  The code you have shared so far does not compile because it lacks a definition for BaseSpecifiedConcreteClassConverter which seems to be critical to the functioning of your current code, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/2qM51J for a demo.  Absent that it's unlikely we will be able to answer your question and show where your current code is not working.  Thanks!

The fact that you make ActionBase inherit from ActionHolder is very puzzling.  Neither OpenURLAction not ScaleAction have an id property as shown in the JSON.  They only have obj_id.  Why did you do that?  Anyway, I'd probably go with something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cerXrr.  Is that the sort of answer you are looking for?

@dbc Hi, thank you for answering and sorry for not clarifying my question clearly.
Great solution! thank you so much!!

I would modify the design of your type hierarchy and JsonConverter as follows:
public class Root // Not shown in your question
{
    public List<Event> events { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Event
{
    public int id { get; set; } // Does this have a fixed value of 1?
    public List<ActionHolder> actions { get; set; } = new();
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(ActionHolderConverter))]
public class ActionHolder
{
    public int id => (int)(values?.id ?? ActionValueType.None);
    public ActionValueBase values { get; set; }
}

public enum ActionValueType
{
    None = -1,
    OpenURL = 8,
    Scale = 15,
}

public abstract class ActionValueBase
{
    [JsonIgnore] public abstract ActionValueType id { get; }
    public int obj_id { get; set; }
}

public class OpenURLActionValue : ActionValueBase
{
    public override ActionValueType id => ActionValueType.OpenURL;
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class ScaleActionValue : ActionValueBase
{
    public override ActionValueType id => ActionValueType.Scale;
    public float scale { get; set; } = 1;
}

And rewrite your JsonConverter as follows:
class ActionHolderConverter : JsonConverter<ActionHolder>
{
    public override ActionHolder ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, ActionHolder existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject joAction = JObject.Load(reader);
        
        var values = (ActionValueType)joAction[nameof(ActionHolder.id)].Value<int>() switch
        {
            ActionValueType.Scale => joAction[nameof(ActionHolder.values)]?.ToObject<ScaleActionValue>(serializer),
            ActionValueType.OpenURL => joAction[nameof(ActionHolder.values)]?.ToObject<OpenURLActionValue>(serializer),
            ActionValueType.None => (ActionValueBase)null,
            var t => throw new JsonSerializationException($"Unknown ActionValueTypes {t}"),
        };
        var holder = existingValue ?? new ActionHolder();
        holder.values = values;
        return holder;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, ActionHolder value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

Key points:

In your design, ActionBase inherits from ActionHolder, but this seems like a mistake.  In your JSON there is a clear distinction between the events[*].actions[*] objects which have two values, "id" and "values", and the nested "values" objects which have an "obj_id" property along with additional properties.  Since there are no common properties between these two, it doesn't make sense to use ActionBase as a base class for both.

I introduced an enum corresponding to the possible values of id.

Since ActionHolder.id is entirely defined by the type of the value, I made it read-only and determined from a virtual read-only property of ActionValueBase which is again determined from the type.

If there is any chance you will want to add to your events and actions collections, I recommend using resizable List<T> lists rather than fixed length arrays for them.


Demo fiddle here.
